# SQL View - Combine multiple rows into 1 row

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a new view using in MSSql 2008 from three tables:
Table 1 has customer id and transaction id
Table 1

```
CustomerID      TransactionID   
1                        1
1                        2
```

Table 2 has Purchases Transaction and Products ID

```
TransactionID    ProductID 
1                     x
2                     y
```

Table 3 has Products Names

```
ProductID   Name  
1            x
2            y
```

I view I would like to make should show

```
CustomerID  Product Name
1              x, y
```

When I use the following query:

```
SELECT     table1. CustomerID, table3.Name 

FROM         table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Table2 ON table2. TransactionID    = table1.VisitId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Table3 ON table2. ProductID  = Table3. ProductID 

                      GROUP BY table1. CustomerID, table3.Name
```

I get

```
CustomerID  Product Name
1           x
1           y
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL. How create list as comma-separated string in one SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621432/t-sql-how-create-list-as-comma-separated-string-in-one-select) from just yesterday

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql concatenated roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624347/sql-concatenated-roles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a user defined function, something like:

```
SELECT table1.CustomerID, dbo.BuildStringOfCustomerProductNames(table1.CustomerID)
FROM table1
```

And create a user defined function like: dbo.BuildStringOfCustomerProductNames
that takes a customerid as input.
Inside there, you can run a query to loop through the table 2 and table 3 joined records to make a string, and return that.

Off hand I can't think of any other simple way to do it.

Comment: Thank Mafu, I would appreciate if you can explain the defined function in more details.

Comment: Well, i think the links provided to your question might be a better answer.  But to do this via a function: I don't have time to really spell it out right now, but basically you would create the function with the customer id as an input.  Create a varchar variable, and create a cursor to loop thru a query that returns the customer's product names.  In each loop, append a comma and the product name to the variable, and return the variable afterword.  This is just an answer.  Not necessarily a good one.